# Should private class member use its own ILogger instance?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, dependency-injection, ilogger

I'm writing a C# library, and am trying to figure out how best to do logging. I want my library to be useable with and without DI.

Suppose my libary has one main public class called `Foo` which accepts an `IBar` dependency via its constructor, but also has a hard-wired private member of type `Qux` (an internal class).

To keep my library logging-framework agnostic, I believe the best practice is to pass an `ILogger<Foo>` to the constructor of `Foo`, and an `ILogger<BarImpl>` to an implementation of `IBar`.

My question is, should `Qux` use the `ILogger<Foo>` logger, or should it have its own logger, `ILogger<Qux>`? If so, how would `Foo` create an `ILogger<Qux>` to pass to `Qux`?

```
public interface IBar {}

public class BarImpl : IBar
{
    public BarImpl(ILogger<BarImpl> logger)
    {
    }
}

internal class Qux
{
    public Qux(ILogger<Qux> logger) // should Qux accept ILogger<Qux> or ILogger<Foo>?
    {
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    private Qux _qux;
    
    public Foo(IBar bar, ILogger<Foo> logger)
    {
        // how to create ILogger<Qux> here?
        // _qux = new Qux();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just inject `Qux` into `Foo` too and let the container figure it out?

Comment: Thank you for this, by both loggers do you mean `ILogger<Foo>` and `ILogger<Qux>`?

Comment: @Llama `Qux` is an internal class which I want to hide from users of `Foo`. It should be considered an implementation detail.

Comment: You could still register it with the container. It would be a little tricky for end users to instantiate it by themselves since it's `internal`. I'm assuming that you have something like `public static ISerivceCollection AddMyLibrary(this IServiceCollection services)` to register the services your library requires, or that you use your own container internally. If that's not the case, ignore me.

Comment: As @CamiloTerevinto says, `ILoggerFactory` is what you should be using for infrastructure-type code like this.

Comment: Problems like this are why I'm very much against injecting loggers: they just get in the way. `private static readonly ILogger logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Qux))` is much more straightforward, although Microsoft.Extensions.Logging doesn't push this approach

Comment: Static dependency resolving is a pain to deal with because you have hidden dependencies all over the place. There is no way when looking at the class signatures to know that there is a hidden dependency on the logging system inside and how that works. In my experience, hidden dependencies will come back to bite you when you least expect it.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Completely agreed with you there. Unit testing that, for example, is a pain in the ***

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen In general, I absolutely agree. However if you're using a logger, you can reasonably expect that to be everywhere: it's no surprise to open a class and find a logger there. There's also a strong argument that loggers are an implementation detail: why does a consumer care whether your class writes debug information or not? Why does a consumer care about setting up that class's logger setup for it? As with anything it's a trade-off, but I find that making an exception for loggers specifically has lots of upsides, and no appreciable downsides in practice

Comment: I understand but the post explicitly said "library" so I guess it depends on how general a library it should be. I really wouldn't want to download Json.net from nuget.org only to find it requires nlog, or whatnot.

Comment: I wouldn't want to download json.net from nuget.org only to find it requires Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, either. Also, there's a difference between a library having a dependency on a logging framework/abstraction (be it Microsoft.Extensions.Logging or anything else), and that library using DI vs static factories to instantiate its loggers. If you are consuming a library, it's a lot easier if you don't have to inject loggers all over the place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few ways of doing this.

1. If you'd like `Qux` to be an implementation detail of `Foo` as it is now, then:

```
public Foo(IBar bar, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Foo>();
    _qux = new Qux(loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Qux>());
}
```

2. If you want to use DI more correctly, and can depend on users correctly using your library (as suggested by @Llama):

```
public Foo(IBar bar, Qux qux, ILogger<Foo> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _qux = qux;
}

// inside your library where you can see the internal Qux
public static IServiceCollection InjectMyLibraryServices(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...
    services.AddScoped<IQux, Qux>();
    services.AddScoped<IFoo, Foo>();
}
```

3. You can get rid of DI for `Qux` and just get the logger (as mentioned by @canton7):

```
public Foo(IBar bar, ILogger<Foo> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _qux = new Qux();
}

internal class Qux 
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Qux));
}
```

*Side note*: this last approach represents the Service Locator anti-pattern and hides the logging dependency. Use only if you understand the pros and cons of doing things this way. I personally wouldn't recommend this approach.

Comment: It's not really a service locator -- a service locator can be used to get any sort of dependency. A static log manager can just be used to get loggers. The scope is significantly less, which mitigates almost all of the concerns