# How to register in Asp.net core 3.1 built in DI an internal interface that can be used from a public controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, interface, internals

I have the following interfaces along with the implementations:

```
public interface IRonaldoContainer{}

public class RonaldoContainer : IRonaldoContainer
{
    private IRonaldo _ronaldo;

    public RonaldoContainer(IRonaldo ronaldo)
    {
       _ronaldo = ronaldo;
    }
}

internal interface IRonaldo
{
    string BestPlayer();
}

internal class Ronaldo : IRonaldo
{
    public string BestPlayer() => "Ronaldo";
}
```

I want to register IRonaldoContainer in the DI(via extension method on `IServiceCollection`) and consume it inside asp.net core controller:

```
public class EmployeesImportController : ControllerBase
{
    private IRonaldoContainer _ronaldoContainer;

    public EmployeesImportController(IRonaldoContainer ronaldoContainer)
    {
        _ronaldoContainer = ronaldoContainer;
    }
}
```

I am developing a Nuget and I aspire that all it's implementation details classes to be internal to not pollute the public Api the Nuget exposes, in this case IRonaldoContainer is the api and IRonaldo is the implementation details I want to hide.

When running the code above I get the following error at run time:

Unable to resolve service for type 'IRonaldoContainer' while attempting to activate 'EmployeeManagement.Controllers.V1.EmployeesImportController'.

I guess that the root cause is that I have an internal dependency and I use the Asp.net core built in DI [Can I make an ASP.NET Core controller internal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824957/can-i-make-an-asp-net-core-controller-internal).

What is the recommended way to solve the problem above? I want my Nuget to hide the implementation details **and** that it will be able to use it easily inside asp.net core application with the built in DI

Comment: A lot of libraries offer an extension method on `IServiceCollection` such as `AddMyServiceName()` so that end users can call `services.AddMyServiceName();`.

Comment: There was a very similar question that I answered 2 days ago, one of the options should surely be what you're after: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68754069/should-private-class-member-use-its-own-ilogger-instance/68754578#68754578

Comment: Your container cannot be resolved, because a Dependency Injection framework or the default have not been implemented. Since it has not been implemented, you cannot indicate which containers should be loaded, so your factory cannot be called with the interface.  Your other option be what was mentioned above, call an extension method to for IServiceCollection, that’ll need be called first before container will map.

Comment: Thanks all for your help!
1. I did exposed an extension method to register all my Nuget dependencies on ```IServiceCollection```
2. I think think that my problem is caused because of asp.net core controller can not deal with internal dependencies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41824957/can-i-make-an-asp-net-core-controller-internal

is it even possible to register on Asp.net core DI internal class and get it inside the asp.net core controller? 
am I missing something?

Comment: Hello was the problem resolved?

Comment: no, hope someone can provide easy way to do it

Comment: keeping `internal` accessor it might not be achieved within this context.